# install python using GUI pyqt

Tags: pyqt, pyqt5, qt5

is it possible to develop a pyqt application and check if python is installed, if not can we install python from the same application?

i need to install python through a pyqt standalone application(exe).
when i double click on the exe it should download python and install.

Comment: Don't know about your specific case, but in general python can be easily installed in a minute through downloading it [from here](https://www.python.org/downloads/) on Windows, and in Linux it is available through command line `sudo apt install python3.8`.

Comment: What is `PyQt standalone application`? Isn't pyqt a library? Or you mean that you wrote some application using pyqt? Then you have to embed there some button that downloads and installs python. If you're under windows then you have to embed [this URL](https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.9.2/python-3.9.2-amd64.exe) into your application. Then download file by this url and run exe program, it should have some flag for silent install.

Comment: @Arty: yes exactly, i need to write a pyqt application, when it downloads and install python as u said, and need to run that executable on a machine which does not have python installed, and install python on that system.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. You will need to do the following:

1. Develop the code on a computer with Python and PyQt, convert the python code into a executable (.exe) file (if you would like to deploy to windows)
2. Send this .exe file to the user computer and then run it there